# Unable to present a view controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uistoryboard

I need to present a view controller from app delegate.

When a phone notification comes in, I am able to decide which one of 3 view controllers (named ForumViewController, BlogViewController & NewsViewController) should be presented by analyzing the 'userInfo' in the method 'didReceiveRemoteNotification'.

But when i try to present the appropriate view controller using storyboards or the code below:

```
self.viewController = [[MembersViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MembersViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then, the app gives the error 'Warning: Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy!'. Also it gets stuck on a particular view controller.

Please keep in mind that the view controllers that I am trying to present are not part of the flow when the app starts (the flow is LogoViewController -> SplashViewController -> HomeViewController).

The HomeViewController & MembersViewController are essentially the main menu pages for public & private viewing. Here I have to display something to the viewer.

Comment: are you using storyboard or xib

Comment: am using 1 storyboard

Answer (score 1):

**choice-1**

**using push**

```
 UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MembersViewController *vc = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MembersViewController"];

[navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**using present**

```
MembersViewController *root = (MembersViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *vc = [root.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MembersViewController"];

[root presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**upadted**

```
  UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MembersViewController* pvc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MembersViewController"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: but it still gives the same error and it does not take me to the view controller i wish to present

Comment: it gives the error 'Warning: Attempt to present <MembersViewController: 0x147063800> on <LogoViewController: 0x146d56680> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!' and if the app is in the background then it just brings the app to the foreground

Comment: it still shows the error '<Warning>: Warning: Attempt to present <MembersViewController: 0x15d04da00> on <LogoViewController: 0x15c64c580> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!' and does not change the viewcontroller...

Comment: in the storyboard, have ticked the LogoViewController as initial view controller....this is linked to the SplashViewController by segue and this is linked to the HomeViewController also by segue...

Answer (score 1):

Loading a view controller from the storyboard:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(ShowModalViewController) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];

-(void)ShowModalViewController{
 NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Identifier of your view controller is either equal to the class name of your view controller, or a Storyboard ID that you can assign in the identity inspector of your storyboard.

Comment: Have tried this solution, but unfortunately still gives me the same warning, and does not take me to the view controller required to be presented to the user

Comment: @user2442902 I have done some edits try that. Because using the performSelector the selector will not be called until the next run of the run loop. So things have time to settle down and you will just skip one run loop